# Python + webkit + gtk on windows

Tags: windows, webkit, gtk, pygtk

I am trying to do this script:
[PY WYSIWYG](http://arstechnica.com/open-source/guides/2009/07/how-to-build-a-desktop-wysiwyg-editor-with-webkit-and-html-5.ars)

And it says I need Gtk and WebKit.
I think this is what I need:

- [Gtk](http://www.gtk.org/download-windows-64bit.html)
- [WebKit](http://nightly.webkit.org/)

So I downloaded WebKit but I got a folder instead of an installer or install information. Do I move it into the python folder or what do I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need PyGTK, here is a link to the download page with install instructions for Windows: http://www.pygtk.org/downloads.html

You also need the Python bindings for Webkit, not just Webkit itself. Here is a link to an unofficial Windows binary, with install instructions, and a link to an unofficial Webkit runtime for Windows near the bottom too:  http://opensourcepack.blogspot.com/2009/12/pywebkitgtk-windows-binary.html

Answer (score 3):

There is [automated installer of (mostly) GTK libraries Python](http://opensourcepack.blogspot.com/2011/01/conservative-all-in-one-pygtk-installer.html). It should have dependencies solved. It is unofficial. It contains webkit. I found it because I wanted webkit installer for Python.

I tried it and it worked like charm.

List of all plugins contained inside of it:

- PyGTK 2.17.0 with numpy support
- PyGobject 2.21.5
- PyCairo 1.8.10
- PyGtkspell, PyGTKhtml2, PyGDL 2.25.3
- PyGDA 2.29.1
- PyGST (Python Gstreamer) 0.10.20
- PyWebkitGTK 1.18
- PyClutter 1.3.2 with gst and gtk binding
- PyGTKGlExt 1.1.0
- PyGoocanvas 0.14.1
- PyGTKSourceview 2.10.0
- PyGTKImageview 1.2.0
- PyRSVG 2.30
- PyScintilla 1.99
- PMing 4.4
- Python Poppler 0.12 GPL
- VIPSCC 7.24

PS: I actually had problem with [other tutorial on webgui in Python mentioned here](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=587180), then I found this page and Your tutorial worked. Thanks. :)

Comment: Antivir found a virus in that installer: TR/Diple.aipm.2
some *glade*.exe