# How do I install pywebkitgtk on Windows?

Tags: python, webkit

How do you install pywebkitgtk on Windows? (Windows 7)

I've seen the answer to this question: [Python + webkit + gtk on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949060/python-webkit-gtk-on-windows/3949905)

But it refers to a binary that is out of date.