# Install pywebkitgtk on windows

Tags: python, webkit, pygtk

How do you do that? I have installed `pygtk`, how can I build `webkit`?

The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21196069/how-do-i-install-pywebkitgtk-on-windows) never got an answer.

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebKit is this helpful? Perhaps `Webware` has what you need.

Comment: @JDong Thanks, but it's not the same as [this](https://code.google.com/p/pywebkitgtk/). Alternatives will also be nice if it is totally unavailable on windows

Comment: You could try building it from source. I see all the files you need in the repo. It will be quite a bit of work on Windows though.

Comment: @JDong That is my question, how do I do that? Where do I start and what tools will I need? I tried VS' `nmake`, didn't work.