# Install webkit and gtk on python 2.7 (windows OS)

Tags: python, windows, webkit, gtk, libraries

I can't install these libs, could somebody help me?

I need the webkit lib and gtk lib:
I've found pygtk and other but i want gtk and webkit as in '[this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JEW50aEVi4k)'

PS:{I've already see '[this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949060/python-webkit-gtk-on-windows)' but I have not understand... }

PPS: {if i can do that only on linux, what distro should I use?}

20:24 - 1/05/2014>>>
I've webkit module but if i try to import it raise:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    import webkit
  File "C:\Python27\lib\webkit.py", line 12, in 
    import sip
ImportError: No module named sip
```

Comment: Do you can an error when you attempt to install these?  If so, what is it?

Comment: PyGI is available for win to, as a all-in-one installer; the gtk3 installer let you choose modules to be instaled, but there are some diff between pygtk - pygi