# Python GUI package with HTML capabilities

Tags: python, html, user-interface, pygtk

I am writing a data processing application that in the end produces an HTML file that can be openend in a browser (chrome,firefox etc.). This HTML file is a google maps page with points plotted (made with the pygmaps package). I want to know if there are any python GUI packages which support the displaying of this google maps with points plotted inside the GUI application.

Comment: sure wx has an iewindow(and with work you can use the chrome render engine) thing that i know can handle js and css pretty well so it will probably work... Im sure qt has simillar capabilities ... less confident that tkinter would

Comment: If you are using pygtk, have a look at http://www.webkitgtk.org/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949060/python-webkit-gtk-on-windows.